# How to know which states are entangled from a state vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

consider the following state vector of three qubits

$$(1/2)|000⟩+(1/2)|011⟩+(1/2)|101⟩+(1/2)|110⟩.$$

how to know which qubits are entangled with respect to their basis states, in other words, how do we conclude in the end the following:

that the superposition of the entangled states are:

$$(1/√2) (|000⟩ + |011⟩)$$ and $$(1/√2) (|101⟩ + |110⟩)$$

and are there any other states that are entangled?

Comment: if there is something unclear in my phrasing please point it out.

Comment: You might find a more receptive audience to these kinds of questions at the quantum computing stack exchange: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

> consider the following state vector of three qubits
>
> 1/2|000⟩+1/2|011⟩+1/2|101⟩+1/2|110⟩
>
> how to know which qubits are entangled with respect to their basis states, in other words, how do we conclude in the end the following:
>
> that the superposition of the entangled states are:
>
> 1/√2 (|000⟩ + |011⟩) and 1/√2 (|101⟩ + |110⟩)

Recall that a state is *not* entangled if it can be written as a direct product of single qubit states. (See N. David Mermin "Quantum Computer Science: An Introduction" at Section 1.5.)

In other words, if your state is *not* entangled then you should be able to write it as:
$$
\left(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle\right)\times
\left(\gamma|0\rangle+\delta|1\rangle\right)\times
\left(\epsilon|0\rangle+\zeta|1\rangle\right)\tag{1}
$$
for *some* $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, $\epsilon$, and $\zeta$.

However, this is impossible. By expanding out the general product state (1) and comparing to your state, we find a contradiction.

There are many different ways to arrive at the contradition.

For example, if you consider the product states in their natural counting order ($000$, $001$, $010$, ...), you first see (by looking at the $|000\rangle$ part) that you must have $\alpha\gamma\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$ and so necessarily $\alpha\neq 0$ and $\gamma \neq 0$ and $\epsilon\neq 0$. You next see that you must have $\zeta=0$ (by looking at the $|001\rangle$ part). You next see that you must have $\delta=0$ (by looking at the $|010\rangle$ part). You next see that you must have $\alpha\delta\zeta=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$ (by looking at the $|011\rangle$ part), but this is a contradiction since we already have established that we must have both $\delta$ and $\zeta$ equal to zero.

Thus, your state *must* be entangled.

> and are there any other states that are entangled?

This part of your question does not make sense to me. We have established that your state is an entangled state. It is not at all clear what you mean by "are there any **other** states that are entangled." (Emphasis added.) We are only considering one state, the state that you proposed...

If you are asking whether or not, in general, there are other three qubit states that are entangled... the answer is yes.